# Getting an iPhone UDID and IMEI from Mobile Safari Using java servlet

Tags: java, ios, iphone, servlets, mobile-safari

I want to get iPhone UDID through Mobile Safari. Iam using 
**.mobileconifg** as

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>PayloadContent</key>
        <dict>
            <key>URL</key>
            <string>http://192.168.12.45:8080/enroll/retrieve</string>
            <key>DeviceAttributes</key>
            <array>
                <string>UDID</string>
                <string>SERIAL</string>
                <string>CHALLENGE</string>
                <string>IMEI</string>
                <string>ICCID</string>
                <string>VERSION</string>
                <string>PRODUCT</string>
                <string>DEVICE_NAME</string>
                <string>MAC_ADDRESS_EN0</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
        <string>Org</string>
        <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
        <key>PayloadVersion</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PayloadUUID</key>
        <string>D6F1B2A3-0039-48B5-915B-8E2B35663816</string>
        <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
        <string>Identifer</string>
        <key>PayloadDescription</key>
        <string>This temporary profile will be used to find and display your current device's UDID.</string>
        <key>PayloadType</key>
        <string>Profile Service</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

**retrieve.php**

```
<?php
  $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
  header('Location: http://192.168.12.45/enroll/info?'.$data, true, 301);
?>
```

info is a  directory and not a page, I have created index.php in this directory I get data in $_GET.

But i am able to get from php.

But i want to use java servlet, i changed url in mobileconfig file on servlet url but i am not able to get any values in java.

**retrieve Java Code**

```
    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String paramName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);
        System.out.println("paramValue :" + paramValue);
    }
```

**Output :**

```
paramValue :192.168.12.45:8080
paramValue :keep-alive
paramValue :gzip, deflate
paramValue :Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53
paramValue :en-us
paramValue :text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

it shows error like this

[image]

But i want java servlet for getting IMEI.
I want to change the above php code to java servlet. 
How to solve this and install Profile to get UDID and IMEI

Comment: That link says: QUIRK WARNING:: **The only way I (& others) have got it working is to redirect to a directory. I've tried to redirect to a .aspx page and it failed. If you do not get this right, then a vague error message will be shown to the user & they will be stuck.** Did you redirect to directory?

Comment: that link says it gives error.

Comment: Neither do I. Just mentioned in case you missed that. sorry!

Answer (score 3):

This is might be due to encryption enabled on your database file or directory containing it.
Use:

`NSFileManager's setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` with `NSFileProtectionNone`

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you want to use a Java servlet instead of PHP. 
According to [this article](http://www.joshwright.com/tips/Getting-an-iPhone-UDID-from-Mobile-Safari),
this might not work,
as it seems the receiving URL specified in your `.mobileconfig` file *must be* a PHP file:

> QUIRK WARNING: For whatever reason, the process is EXTREMELY particulary about how your server responds when it sends the user to your preset URL. After many tries, I believe that your receiving url MUST be a .php file. This sounds nuts but I'm serious.

But you could try anyway.
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295897/641955),
this Java code should be roughly equivalent to PHP's `php://input`,
this this in your servlet:

```
    InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (stream.read(buffer) != -1) {
        builder.append(new String(buffer));
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
```

If that still doesn't work,
I suppose you have no choice but to do what the author of the article did,
and use PHP just to redirect to the servlet.
In that case, it will be better if in `retrieve.php`, 
you need to pass `$data` as a named query parameter, 
by changing `'/info?'.$data` to `'/info?data='.$data`, like this:

```
<?php
  $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
  header('Location: http://192.168.12.45/enroll/info?data='.rawurlencode($data));
?>
```

I also wrapped `$data` in `rawurlencode($data)`, and removed the extra parameters that don't seem to be necessary.

Then in your servlet, you can access the `data` parameter like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String data = request.getParameter("data");
    System.out.println(data);
}
```